# Use a function to add and one to remove an object from an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I haven't be able to use the push() method to use the new Food constructor to create new items in my pantry array. I need a function to call that will add objects to the array, and I would like for the id value to be calculated based on the current length of the array.

I have tried to create functions like

```
groceries = function ()
{ 
    pantry.push(new Food)};


    var pantry = 
    [
    egg = new Food (1, "Egg", ...)
    ...
    ...
    ];


    function Food (id, name,...)
    {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    ...
    };
    this.inquiry = function() {
        return '\n' + this.name + 
        '\n' +
    };
```

I can go to the browser and `pantry.push(chicken = new Food(... arguments...);` but I'm coming up short on knowledge in how to construct a function that would make the process cleaner. I'm not sure if this is just how it is. Maybe I can't do this with a constructor in mind. I'm very new.

I expect there is a way to type in a function that will use my constructor to format new variables and then push them to the end of my pre made variable pantry. I'd like to be able to use this function in the browser.

so far i'm getting errors like function not defined or syntax error.

Comment: Why are you assigning the `egg` variable inside the array literal?

Comment: Is `function Food` really supposed to be nested inside the `groceries` function?

Comment: No. I'm new to the website and didn't proof read carefully while developing my question. Is it fine to start a new question? My title isn't worded properly either. Sorry for all that.

I defined egg in the array literal because I thought that's how i should do it. Ultimately I would like a program where i can type in on a document what my food will contain in nutrients and it's cash value per serving. I'd also like the ability to remove objects from the array. 

This is my homework from a person helping me learn.

Comment: You should edit the question to clarify it, rather than write a new question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean `class` instead of function. `new` can only use for `class`. Like below.

```js
class Food {

  constructor(id, name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
  }

  inquiry() {
    return '\n' + this.name + '\n';
  }
}

var pantry = [ new Food(1, "Egg") ];

console.log(pantry);
console.log(pantry[0].inquiry());
```

Comment: if I understand the question correctly, he want the ID to be auto-generated with the current array length, so maybe adding this would be great: function addToPantry(name) { pantry.push(new Food(pantry.length + 1, name)) }

Comment: *"`new` can only be used for class"* `class` was introduced in ES2015. You can use new on [constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/new) too

Comment: Thank you for the clarification adiga. I'd like the id to be auto generated, but i'm struggling with creating a function that can be used to add new objects for example, when i got to the browser and go to the console I may type

     pantry.push(chicken = new Food(pantry.length, "chicken", 1, .50, 40, 80, 10, 5, 60));

and that will add the new food, but i'm looking to make a function so that the process is cleaner. I'm learning JavaScript as my first language.

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another solution you could use

```js
class FoodStore{
constructor() {
    this.data = [];
  }
  
 add(name){
  this.data.push({id: this.data.length,name});
  }
 
 toList(){
   return this.data;
  }
 
}

var store = new FoodStore();
store.add("test");
//inquiry
console.log(store.toList()[0].name);

// All items
console.log(store.toList());
```